# Using the Cut to Increase Efficiency

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

If I have the following knowledge base, how do I add a cut to the parent_of term so that if an X is already determined to be a father, prolog won't attempt to "check" if X is also a mother?

```
father_of(max,john).
father_of(max,james).
father_of(max,gabe).
mother_of(june,john).
mother_of(june,james).

parent_of(X,Y) :- father_of(X,Y).
parent_of(X,Y) :- mother_of(X,Y).
```

For example, I want:

parent_of(max,Y) to be: Y=john, Y=james, Y=gabe

parent_of(june,Y) to be: Y=john, Y=james

For the first one, I don't want prolog to even attempt to check if max is a mother_of since it was already determined that he is a father_of.

I've already tried so many combinations including:

```
parent_of(X,Y) :- father_of(X,Y),!.  <-- fixes an X and Y and thus will list only Y=john
parent_of(X,Y) :- !,father_of(X,Y). <-- works for parent_of(max,Y) but not parent_of(jane)
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Doing such optimizations is extremely tricky. And Prolog is quite performing in such matters without any optimizations.

But as a general rule: You cannot simply set the cut into the program, you need to perform all kinds of tests in advance. I suspect that those tests are easily more expensive than the overhead you intend to remove. Here is an attempt. Honestly, I have not a very good feeling, because you should rather learn pure Prolog first.

So we assume that there is no solution to: `?- father_of(P,_), mother_of(P,_).`

```
parent_of(F, C) :-
   (  atom(F), \+ \+ father_of(F, _) -> !
   ;  true
   ),
   father_of(F, C).
parent_of(M, C) :-
   mother_of(M, C).
```

Is this really better? Maybe, and maybe not.

But in any case, you have already understood one important point: clever optimizations require extensive testing. I believe above is correct, but I am not even sure that this will be faster. After all, there are now two lookups for `father_of/2` in place of one for `father_of/2` and one for `mother_of/2`. The naive version might be readily faster...

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, some Prolog systems offer a "soft cut" `*->/2`:

```
parent_of(X,Y) :- father_of(X,Y) *-> true ; mother_of(X,Y).
```

In general for `If *-> Then ; Else`, if the condition `If` succeeds, `Then` is executed, an on backtracking only alternative solutions for `If` and `Then` are returned. Only in the case that `If` has no solutions at all, `Else` is executed.

This requires you to know the mode, i.e., the calling pattern, of your predicate. In your case, if the mode of your predicate `parent_of` is `parent_of(++,?)`, then adding a soft cut is fine (assuming that names are unique or appear only for one gender). In the case of `parent_of(++,++)`, even a regular cut would be fine, though unnecessary unless you have duplicate facts in your database (symmetry breaking is one use case for cuts). However, if you also have to cater for `parent_of(-,?)`, then a cut really cuts away solutions.

In general: only use cuts when you are sure that the branch(es) of the search tree that you cut away contain no solutions, or only symmetric solutions that you are not interested in.

Comment: Your solution is not what OP asked for. OP asked "if an X is already determined to be a father Prolog won't attempt to "check" if X is also a mother". Now consider `X` being a father and `Y` some unrelated person: You fail and try `mother_of/2`... In any case good multi-argument indexing is probably much better...

Comment: OP's examples were `parent_of(++,-)`, so I'd say that my solution is exactly what OP asked for. As I said, it depends on the modes that the predicate is used in.

Comment: what do you mean by `++`? I have never seen this. I know `+`. And what precisely by `-`? There are several meanings to it. How can you ensure both?

Comment: `++`: fully instantiated, `+`: instantiated, but maybe only partially. Coming from ECLiPSe, I always found this a useful distinction, even though it's not ISO, as I now realize. `-`: unbound at call. Ensuring the ISO meaning is of course difficult, which I guess is the reason that it's not used much.

Comment: Nur sure why you think that ISO meaning is difficult. In ISO, the (templates and) modes are here to produce corresponding errors. There is no ambiguity. But in other context, `-` has (at least) two different meanings: That the argument has no influence, but may be nonvar ; or that it must be free. BTW, where is `++` defined? I did some search prior to asking...